# Is there a list of phones that will work with Ubuntu for Android

Tags: ubuntu-for-android

Ubuntu for Android sounds intriguing and I am interested in checking it out but was wondering if anyone knows which phone/models have the necessary specs and available docks to work with it.

** edit **

After further searching it looks like Ubuntu for Android will primarily be pre-installed so it probably won't be the case of spec'ing out a phone and installing it like I originally thought.

Answer (score 1):

**HTC Android smartphones/tablets (such as G2 Phone, Nexus One)**

I got this information only but the mobile devices which have the following specifications can deal with Ubuntu Android.

```
Dual-core 1 GHz CPU
Video acceleration: shared kernel driver with associated X driver; OpenGL, ES/EGL
Storage: 2GB for OS disk image
HDMI: video-out with secondary frame-buffer device
USB host mode
512 MB RAM
```

So any phone which can meet those specifications can get Ubuntu.

Comment: I was aware of what the requirements are, I was wondering if Ubuntu had compiled a list of manufacturers and models that were meeting those specs - rather than sifting through the specs of dozens of phones.

Comment: i think they are on the way  , Ubuntu site also not mentioned any information on that . actually i am eager to get one .